# Why querySelector work and $() or document.getElementById doesn't work with checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, selectors-api

This is from Lynda.com's course "Jquery Essentianl Training", and from one of the solution's there's a point that I really can't understand.
The assignment is to create checkboxes, and show and hide items with certain data attribute based on whether it's checked or not.

```
document.querySelector('#vitamincheck').addEventListener('change',function (evt) {
        updateProductView("vitamins", evt.target.checked);
    });
    document.querySelector('#mineralcheck').addEventListener('change',function (evt) {
        updateProductView("mineralwater", evt.target.checked);
    });
    document.querySelector('#proteincheck').addEventListener('change',function (evt) {
        updateProductView("proteinbar", evt.target.checked);
    });
    function updateProductView(categoryName, visibility) {

        var dataSelectorVal = "";
        switch (categoryName) {
        case "vitamins":
            dataSelectorVal = "h2[data-type='vitamin']";
            break;
        case "mineralwater":
            dataSelectorVal = "h2[data-type='mineralwater']";
            break;
        case "proteinbar":
            dataSelectorVal = "h2[data-type='proteinbar']";
            break;
        }

        $(".product-item").has(dataSelectorVal).css('display', visibility ? "" : "none");

    }
```

I can understand why it works.
But the problem is when I try to change document.querySelector('#someid') to
$('#someid') or document.getElementById('#someid'),
it doesn't work.

I have googled quite a bit, and if I am pointing to a certain ID, docuemnt.querySelector and $() should behave the same way.
Am I missing something here??

Or if it's checkbox, it should be selected only by document.querySelector?

BTW, HTML bits related to above javascript is as below.

```
    <p>SHOW: <input type="checkbox" id="vitamincheck" value="vitamin" checked="checked"> Vitamins
<input type="checkbox" id="mineralcheck" value="mineralwater" checked="checked"> Mineral Water
<input type="checkbox" id="proteincheck" value="proteinbar" checked="checked"> Protein Bar</p>

<ul class="product-list">
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-A1037">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-a.jpg" alt="Vitamin A - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Vitamin A</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-BC2178">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-bcomplex.jpg" alt="B Complex - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Vitamin-B Complex</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="MW-8812">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/mineralwater-blueberry.jpg" alt="Blueberry Mineral Water - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="mineralwater">Blueberry Mineral Water</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-C6614">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-c.jpg" alt="Vitamin C - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Vitamin C</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="PB-8154">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/proteinbar-chocolate.jpg" alt="Protein Bar Chocolate - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="proteinbar">Chocolate Protein Bar</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-CA4543">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-calcium.jpg" alt="Vitamin Calcium - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Calcium Vitamin</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-D1825">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-d.jpg" alt="Vitamin D - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Vitamin D</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-F2225">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-flaxseed-oil.jpg" alt="Flaxseed Oil - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Flaxseed Oil Vitamin</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-I7456">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-iron.jpg" alt="Vitamin Iron - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Iron Vitamin</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="MW-9143">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/mineralwater-lemonlime.jpg" alt="Mineral Water Lemon Lime - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="mineralwater">Lemon Lime Mineral Water</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-M0019">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-magnesium.jpg" alt="Vitamin Magnesium - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Magnesium Vitamin</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-MV7763">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-multi.jpg" alt="Vitamin Multivitamin - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Multi-vitamin</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="PB-1234">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/proteinbar-peanutbutter.jpg" alt="Vitamin Protein Bar Peanut Butter - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="proteinbar">Peanut Butter Protein Bar</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="MW-S0987">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/mineralwater-strawberry.jpg" alt="Mineral Water Strawberry - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="mineralwater">Strawberry Mineral Water</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="PB-1919">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/proteinbar-lemon.jpg" alt="Protein Bar Lemon - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="proteinbar">Lemon Protein Bar</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="MW-O1980">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/mineralwater-orange.jpg" alt="Mineral Water Orange - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="mineralwater">Orange Mineral Water</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="MW-P1968">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/mineralwater-peach.jpg" alt="Mineral Water Peach - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="mineralwater">Peach Mineral Water</h2>
</li>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="MW-R2003">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/mineralwater-raspberry.jpg" alt="Mineral Water Raspberry - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="mineralwater">Raspberry Mineral Water</h2>
</li>
</ul><!-- product-list -->
```

Comment: Please define "_doesn't work_". Also, `querySelector()` and `$()` are not even near equivalent. The former returns a HTML element, the latter returns a jQuery object. `document.getElementById('#someid')` "doesn't work"  simply because `#` is not a part of the id of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery, you should add event listners with `on` jQuery method, not `addEventListener` method of vanilla JS. Just replace
`addEventListener` with `on`:

```
$('#vitamincheck').on('change', function (evt) {
    updateProductView("vitamins", evt.target.checked);
});
$('#mineralcheck').on('change', function (evt) {
    updateProductView("mineralwater", evt.target.checked);
});
$('#proteincheck').on('change', function (evt) {
    updateProductView("proteinbar", evt.target.checked);
});
```

Comment: YES now it works like magic with your advice. Thank you so much!  So when I select element with jQuery, then vanilla JS method cannot be applied to it? and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, you can use only jQuery methods when you use `$` for selecting elements. Because actually `$` is a function, so when you write `$('SOMETHING').someMethod` you create a chain of jQuery methods: `$` as first method and `someMethod` as second.

Comment: @Chris Done! Thanks for the tip. I didn't even know how to mark it as the answer until you pointed it out!

Comment: Glad to hear it, tthustla. Thanks @Chris.

Comment: @AlexanderReznikov OK Now I really understand why! Thank you so much for your kind advice!